# Check if a resource is available in google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I'm using this code to know in how much time my session will expire at my university.

```
function checkRemaining() {
    var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhReq.open("GET", "http://192.168.168.168/dynUserLogin.html?loginDone=1", false);
    xhReq.send();

    var regex = /Login session time remaining: ([0-9]+) minutes/g;
    var res = regex.exec(xhReq.responseText);

    return res[1];
}
```

However it produces errors when I'm not connected to my university's internet.

When searching about this error most of the people had it because they were using AdBlock
but in my case (and I guess other people have it too) sometimes the resource may just not be available. How can I trigger a function if the requests fails?

[image: chrome status failed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XMLHttpRequets will [tell you what the result was](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started#Step_2_.E2.80.93_Handling_the_server_response).

```
if (xhReq.status === 200) {
    // perfect!
} else {
    // there was a problem with the request,
    // for example the response may contain a 404 (Not Found)
    // or 500 (Internal Server Error) response code
}
```